# Imprimir algoritmo Yates-Fisher

Tags: python

```
import random 

def aleatorio (arr, n): 

    for i in range(n-1,0,-1): 

        j = random.randint(0,i+1) 


        arr[i],arr[j] = arr[j],arr[i] 
    return arr 


arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] 
n = len(arr) 
print(aleatorio(arr, n))
```

---

Salida del programa: [1, 8, 6, 4, 5, 7, 3, 2]

Salida que se me pide: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola, ya genere mi algoritmo Yates-Fisher pero unicamente me imprime mi arreglo final y necesito que imprima cada paso que implementa el algortimo, espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Hola. Si el sitio no te deja publicar la pregunta porque esta muy corta, la solución no es llenarla de caracteres innecesarios. Como puedes ver, te falta indicar cuál es la salida deseada con ejemplos y es por eso que está el límite inferior para la publicación de la pregunta.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la sugerencia. Ya lo corregi

Answer (score 1):

Pues, cuando haces print del llamado al método, imprimes lo que retorna ,es decir, el arreglo ya modificado.

Seguro no es lo más elaborado pero, y si vas imprimiendo dentro del for en el método cada vez que mueves elementos?

```
import random 

def aleatorio (arr, n): 

    for i in range(n-1,0,-1): 

        j = random.randint(0,i+1) 

        arr[i],arr[j] = arr[j],arr[i]

        print arr 

    return arr 

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] 
n = len(arr) 
print(aleatorio(arr, n))
```